# Did Orichimaru use the real bodies of the First and Second Hokage against the Third on the rooftop?

Tags: naruto

I just wanna know if it was the real bodies, if so, wouldn’t they be like skeletons??

Comment: Edo Tensei uses a living or recently killed body. However, as mentioned below, the full jutsu also encases the human sacrifice in ash, and sort of "reforms" them into the reincarnated one.

Answer (score 3):

Orochimaru used the bodies of [Zaku](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Zaku_Abumi) and [Kin](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Kin_Tsuchi) to summon the Hokage.
The jutsu basically recreates the body of the reincarnated person at the time of their death using the body of the sacrifice.

> To actually perform the Impure World Reincarnation, the DNA of the person to be reincarnated is smeared on a special scroll. Once the scroll is activated, the remains spread out in the form of a special seal with the living sacrifice in the centre. Then dust and ash encase the sacrifice's body, giving them the same appearance that the reincarnated had at the time of their death; the process is apparently painful for the sacrifice.

[Wiki](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Summoning%3A_Impure_World_Reincarnation#Usage)